# Insert date in mysql using html5 input tag

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="collect.php" method="post">
date:<input type="date" name="date"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This form accepts date and sends it to collect.php which is as follows

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
echo "Databse connect error";
die();
}
else echo "successfully connected <br/>";
$date=$_POST['date'];
$adddate="INSERT INTO `testform`.`date`(date) VALUES(".$date.")";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$adddate);
if($result==TRUE)
    echo "date added asuccessfully";
else echo "problem in date";
?>
```

The problem is that it echos date added successfully but when i check in my phpmyadmin result is 0000-00-00
I don't understand the reason.Have tried almost everything i could.please help...

Comment: Please read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and update your code accordingly.

Comment: when i am not allowing the user to input anything else but date,how can there be sql injection?@JasonMcCreary

Comment: Do you think a spammer/hacker will use your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Quotes around your date

```
$date=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['date']);
$adddate="INSERT INTO `testform`.`date`(date) VALUES('".$date."')";
                                                     ^         ^
```